# Directory names with blanks - recursive file check

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

To check the play length of audio files, I'm using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in $(find . -type d); do
cd $dir

for file in *.ogg *.wav *.mp3
do
  duration=$(ffprobe "$file" 2>&1 | awk '/Duration/ { print $2 }')
  echo -e "$duration\t$file"
done | sort -n

cd - > /dev/null
done
```

Where the directories being read recursively contain no spaces in the names, this works fine.

When there is a space in the directory name, the first and second parts become separated in the $dir variable, so...

- dir 1

becomes

- dir

and

- 1

Unfortunately my scripting knowledge is lacking, so I'd be hugely grateful if someone could point me in the right direction so that the full directory name is passed into the variable.

Many thanks,

James.

Comment: Have a look here: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice) - simplest would probably be to replace the outer for loop with a null-delimited while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```bash
for dir in $(find . -type d); do
cd $dir
```

use

```bash
find . -type d -print0 | while read -r -d $'\0' dir; do
cd "$dir"
```

Comment: Thank you!  :) :)